# openSUSE in Hyper-V suddenly goes to black screen

Tags: screen, hyper-v, opensuse

I have Windows 11 laptop with 64GB RAM & NVIDIA GeForce MV550 graphic card. I am running Windows 10 & openSUSE linux as virtual machines in my laptop in Hyper-V.
When my openSUSE is not used for few some time like 30mins and then when I try to go to the VM, the screen is becoming black. At the same time my Windows 10 VM is working fine even after 1hr unused. I had to restart my openSUSE from Hyper-V which is destroying my unsaved work. Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: This question lacks details like which version of openSUSE, and what desktop environment is in use.